# How to delete connect.sid from cookie

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

My project is react + nodejs + express, and I am using passport with oauth strategy to authenticate.

I have some specific scenario, if OAuth authenticated successfully, I still need to check the role of the user in the callback endpoint of Oauth in nodejs side, so if user's role is not allowed. I will need to remove the session in case next time he will pass the oauth authenticate by below code:

```
app.get('/auth/check', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.status(200);
    res.send("authorization passed");
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.status(401);
    res.send("authorization failed");
    //res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}
```

but I cannot remove connect.sid by

```
req.logOut();
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid', {
          path : "/"
        });
```

Comment: Please help, thanks!

Comment: Is the problem that the cookie is not being deleted, even though you have called `res.clearCookie()`? Or is the problem something different?

Comment: The problem is the cookie is not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at

> https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/507#issuecomment-328290070

You can change your code to

`res.clearCookie('connect.sid', {path: '/'}).status(200).send('Ok.');`

Above code works fine for me.

Thank you.

Comment: the link is no longer works and the clear func does not delete the cookie

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with a few similar technologies recently so thought I might share my findings with newer versions of these packages.

At time for writing the latest stable versions are.
express-session v1.17.3
passport v0.6.0 (local strat)

I was reading conflicting opinions on what I needed to do all across the web. In the end, these little tidbits sorted it for me.

In your backend logout function use these:

```
req.session = null;
res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
```

So it may look something like:

```
exports.logout = (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to log out' });
    }

    req.session = null;
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
    res.send({
      message: 'Logged out',
      isAuth: req.isAuthenticated()
    })
  });
};
```

On the frontend ensure you're sending the credentials (cookies - if using the local strategy) when submitting the logout form, for example (using axios):

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3001/logout", {}, {
    withCredentials: true
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of your problem:

```
exports.postLogout = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await UserService.logout(req);
    return res
      .status(200)
      .clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' })
      .json({ status: 'Success' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
};
```

This is what UserService logout does:

```
async logout(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.logout(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          resolve({ status: 'Success' });
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```